# callback failing even though GitHub Installation access Token gets generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api, referenceerror

I have this code for generating an Installation Access Token:

```
gitInstallationAccessToken.getAccessTokensUrl(jwt, function(appAccessTokensUrl) {

  var instance = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: appAccessTokensUrl,
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
      "Authorization" : `Bearer ${jwt}`
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var installationAccessToken = response.data.token;
    console.log(`Installation Access Token: ${installationAccessToken}`)
    callback(installationAccessToken);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.warn("Unable to authenticate");
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
    // that falls out of the range of 2xx
    if (error.response) {
      console.warn(`Status ${error.response.status}`);
      console.warn(`${error.response.data.message}`);
    }
  });
});
```

It outputs `Unable to authenticate` so is failing at some point. My issue is that `console.log('Installation Access Token: ${installationAccessToken}')` outputs a token so I would expect the callback to succeed. Is there any reason why it's likely to fail?

**Additional info**

This is the actual error returned in the catch:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at eval (webpack:///./lib/githubService.js?:17:51)
    at Object.retrieveIssues (webpack:///./lib/githubService.js?:87:6)
    at eval (webpack:///./lib/getPublicGitHubIssues.js?:78:20)
    at eval (webpack:///./lib/gitInstallationAccessToken.js?:84:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Looks like this might relate to Solution 2 of [this](https://esausilva.com/2017/07/11/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-two-solutions/). I'm not sure where the last two steps would go though.

Comment: Your `callback` is probably throwing an error.  You should get rid of that and return a promise instead.

Comment: What is the error in the catch actually printing? As someone else mentioned, you are getting an error elsewhere and because the .then precedes the .catch, catch is going to do its job and catch anything from upstream.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I've added the error to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `babel-plugin-transform-regenerator` and added `import 'babel-polyfill'` to the top of the problem file. Seems to have resolved the issue although it doesn't really make sense to me.